# Can I use Opencart 2.x modules with Opencart 3.x?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I want to use [this](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=7418) Opencart CFO Custom Formulas module which is compatible with Opencart 2.3.0.2, but will it work with Opencart 3.x?

Comment: The compatibilities are shown on the right of the website. No 3.x announced there, and chances are very high that they won't work for a different major version, ESPECIALLY, when you supposed to pay money for it.

Comment: This question is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611645/are-opencart2-extensions-supported-by-opencart3 but it does not have an accepted answer so I can't vote to close.

Comment: your link says that there is that module for the OC3.x version as well. So if you have a legal module, OC 3 versions can also be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Officially you can't do this because of Twig templates, in Opencart 3.0 they added Twig support, so template file for 3.0 version differs from oc 2.3, but, if have programming skills you can get necessary functions from Modules. Controllers or Models can be derived from 2.3 to 3.x.