# Are Opencart2 extensions supported by Opencart3?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I haven't used Opencart3 yet, but would like to use the extensions I have from Opencart2 when migrating to Opencart3. Is that possible out-of-the box, or do the old extensions require changes to adapt them to Opencart3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCart 2 extensions will **not** work in OpenCart 3 without modification.  Even minor things have changed such as the name of the token used in the URL, so there's no chance anything from OpenCart 2 will work with OpenCart 3.